# ように at the end of a sentence

Tags: particle-に, sentence, sentence-final-particles

たとえ分かってもらえなくても

好きだってことを覚えてあげるように

My interpretation was that ようにする

So he's saying

たとえ分かってもらえなくても

好きだってことを覚えてあげるように

Even if I'm not understood.

好きだってことを覚えてあげるように

This should be saying that by doing this, he can make people understand he "likes" them.

For context, the main character has problems expressing himself. However, by doing this thing that people don't understand, he feels like he can make them understand he likes them.

Comment: It's a strange thing to say if the speaker is the one who does the remembering (i.e. the subject of 覚える). More context would help.

Answer (score 0):

More context is needed, until that...

> 好きだってことを覚えてあげるように（している）

Remember that ようにする means "to do so that" and it implies effort and try.

Literally: "I do [it] so that they give me the act of acquiring the fact that I love them. "

Idiomatically: "I try to make them know I love them."

> This should be saying that by doing this, he can make people understand he "likes" them.

This is not correct because ようにする (meaning "to try to") doesn't imply success, but only that you do something in a way that you (may) get a certain result.

Comment: `they give me the act of acquiring the fact that I love them` -- それだと「好きだってことを覚えて**もらう** 」になっちゃいますねえ・・